# How to correctly create a json response of a logged in user for react

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, json, django

I started to try react and tried to simply get the logged in user info but this does not seem to work. I have a Django view to display the user data:

```
def user_details_view(request, *args, **kwargs): #REST API for detailing some basic info about the user that is using the system at the moment
    current_user = request.user
    id = current_user.id
    try:
        obj = CustomUser.objects.get(id=id)
        data =obj.serialize()
    except:
        #data['message'] = "Not Found"
        status = 404
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

I set this view in the urls and if I access it I get the data I want. However, when I try it on react I get an internal server error. Here is the code so far:

```
function loadUserInfo(callback){
  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  const method = 'GET';
  const url = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/userdetails/";
  const responseType = "json";
  xhr.responseType = responseType; // Let the xhr request know that its getting a json 
  xhr.open(method, url); //This opens the request with the method and url entered
  xhr.onload = function(){
    console.log("This is the response: ",xhr.response)
    callback(xhr.response, xhr.status)
  }
  xhr.onerror = function(){
    callback({"message":"The request was an error"}, 400)
  }
  xhr.send();//Trigger that request
}
function App() {
  const [info, setinfo] = useState(null)
  useEffect(()=>{
    const myCallBack = (response,status)=>{
      console.log(response,status)
      if (status === 200){
        setinfo(response)
      }
    }
    loadUserInfo(myCallBack)
  },[])
```

I dealt with the cors and allowed hosts in the settings.py file so I no loger get those issues. What I do get on the django server log is:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'data' referenced before assignment
```

I deleted the try blocks as they can be a bit redundant at the moment but I get a different error:

```
Restaurant_Project/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 435, in get
    raise self.model.DoesNotExist(
accounts.models.CustomUser.DoesNotExist: CustomUser matching query does not exist.
```

This same error occurs if I access the view url in the Django server and I am not logged in. I would like to know what is the best way to pass the user information I want so I use it on React. What I am basically trying to do is to bring the user data from the django response to the front end or React.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the `UnboundLocalError` is because data is not defined if an exception occurs.

Change the lines to:

```
def user_details_view(request, *args, **kwargs): #REST API for detailing some basic info about the user that is using the system at the moment
    current_user = request.user
    id = current_user.id
    data = dict()
    status = 200
    try:
        obj = CustomUser.objects.get(id=id)
        data = obj.serialize()
    except:
        data['message'] = "Not Found"
        status = 404
    return JsonResponse(data, status=status)
```

Comment: I tried your solution and now I get a `GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/userdetails/ 404 (Not Found)`. Again I believe it is due to login as if I logout and try to access the api url I get the same error

Comment: So you mean irrespective of whether the user is logged in or out you're getting a 404 back?

Comment: No, only if the user is not logged in and I try to access the api through the Django server url I get the error. But If I try on React I get the error regardless if I am logged in. I believe this could be due to using different servers which is what I want to accomplish. If the user is logged in then React can read the api data but if no user is then it does not matter as the React components will be only access once a user is logged in.